# Getting python3-config path right for vim install

Tags: linux, vim, python, clipboard, anaconda

I am trying to install vim from source in Ubtuntu 20.04, with both python3 support, and with clipboard support. For that, I am using the instructions presented in the [plugin site](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source), particularly, the following modified ./config call (where I copied the call of the link and added clipboard support):

```
./configure --with-features=huge \
            --enable-multibyte \
            --enable-rubyinterp=yes \
            --enable-python3interp=yes \
            --with-python3-config-dir=$(python3-config --configdir) \
            --enable-perlinterp=yes \
            --enable-luainterp=yes \
            --enable-gui=gtk2 \
            --enable-cscope \
            --with-x \
            --prefix=/usr/local
```

However, after I run this and then `make` and `sudo make install`, the compiled vim doesn't have python3 support. What I think is happening, is that `$(python3-config --configdir)` prints out the config path of my `conda` python install, i.e. `/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu`, and when I run make, it returns at the end:

```
lto1: fatal error: bytecode stream in file ‘/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.a’ generated with LTO version 6.0 instead of the expected 8.1                                               
compilation terminated.
lto-wrapper: fatal error: gcc returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
/usr/bin/ld: error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
link.sh: Linking failed
make[1]: *** [Makefile:2062: vim] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/daniel/vim/src'
make: *** [Makefile:29: first] Error 2
```

Which seems to indicate that a given version of LTO is expected, but conda Python was installed with an older version.

I have tried looking for the system python config, which I believe is the one found in `/usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu`, and subtitute the flag `--with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu \`, but it still seems to try the install with conda python.

Strangely, I got vim working a couple of days ago, just like I wanted, but something must have changed since then (I installed a library with pip, I don't know if that can be the cause), because I suddenly lost clipboard support, and now I can't get things to run again.

In between my tries to make things work I run `sudo make distclean` inside the vim source directory.

How can I make vim run again? How can I have vim use my system python version instead of the conda one? Or what other possible solutions are there? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that allowed me to install vim with the required support.

What I did is setting two different flags pointing to my system python:

```
./configure --with-features=huge \
--enable-python3interp=dynamic \
--with-python3-command=/usr/bin/python3.8 \
--with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu \
--with-x
```

So, besides the --with-python-config-dir, I also added --with-python3-command to the system python executable and this allowed me to install Vim. It was more trial and error than a huge insight or knowledge though

Comment: Please mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: I'm told by the site that I can't accept it for 2 days (now 20 hours to go). I'll accept it when I'm able to. Thanks